# How to connect VMs and Hosts on remote VM-Workstation

Tags: windows, networking, vmware-workstation

I am in my home wifi network, have 2 Win-10 Hosts. On both I run VMWare-Workstations-15, on both I run Ubuntu VMs.

I want to communicate with my VMs (running in the other Host/VMW) from 1st Host.

From my first Host I can ping the other Host, but I can not ping the VM running on that host. The Workstation Networking is default NAT.

How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Bridged Networking mode for the virtual machines. This will allow VMs to connect to the host system physical network. This will enable VMs to obtain IP from the home wifi network and the VMs will appear as a additional computer in the same network & can communicate each other.

Comment: @S RATH - I see the option of Bridged Network. But plenty of options - Do I pick "Replicate Physical network state".  OK I tried -  **it works** - I could ping it at least. Let me see if I can putty into it

Comment: **Yes I could ping putty into it.**